# SwiftUI - Index out of range

Tags: arrays, foreach, swiftui

I start by adding some integers to an array in onAppear for my outermost stack. But when I try to display the contents of the array using ForEach, I get an index out of range error.

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var answers = [Int]()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<4) { number in 
            Text("\(answers[number])")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
           for _ in (0..<4) {
               answerArray.append(Int.random(in: 1...10))
           }
        }
```

Comment: Do `ForEach(answers.indices)` instead of `ForEach(0..<4)`

Comment: That stopped it from crashing, but only because it thinks there are no elements in the array.

Comment: It's right, there *are* no elements in the array, at least at first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never retrieve items by hard-coded indices in a `ForEach` expression.

Do `count` the array, the loop is skipped (safely) if the array is empty.

```
ForEach(0..<answers.count) { number in
```

Or - still simpler – enumerate the items rather than the indices

```
ForEach(answers, id: \.self) { answer in 
    Text("\(answer)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onAppear` is called after `MyView` loads for the first time, and at that moment, `answers` is still empty. That's why your program crashes at `ForEach(0..<4)`, because `answers`'s doesn't have 4 elements yet.

```
ForEach(0..<4) { number in 
    Text("\(answers[number])") /// answers is still empty.
}
```

Instead, you should look over `answers.indices`, so that `answers[number]` is guaranteed to exist. Make sure to also provide an id (`id: \.self`) to satisfy `ForEach`'s `Identifiable` requirement.

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var answers = [Int]()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(answers.indices, id: \.self) { number in
                Text("\(answers[number])")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            for _ in (0..<4) {
                answers.append(Int.random(in: 1...10)) /// you probably meant `answers.append`, not `answerArray.append`
            }
        }
    }
}
```